# Get access to shared memory through semaphores

Tags: c, process, fork, semaphore

I have a different number of process which should write on the shared memory that I already defined. I'm trying by using system V semaphores. The semaphore (`sem_access`) is initialized at 1.

```
    sem_access.sem_op = -1;
    semop(sem_access_id, &sem_access, 1);

    info->index++;
    printf ("INDEX= %d\n", info->index);

    sem_access.sem_op = 1;
    semop(sem_access_id, &sem_access, 1);
```

The problem is that the `printf` prints always the same number, without increment the index.
PS: Sorry for my bad english, but I'm spanish.
edit: if I insert a `sleep(1)` it works well, but i really I don't want the sleep!

Comment: What's the return value from your `semop()` calls?  You're ignoring that.

Comment: It returns 0, no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide some more info about your code. What problem you are getting ? Does your process get stuck once resources acquired or not waiting ?

man page of `semop()` says :

1) If `sem_op` is `less than zero`, the process must have alter permission  on
       the  `semaphore set`. So if `sem_access.sem_op = -1`; when other process will make this value 0 or greater than 0 then only this process will access shared resources.

**process 1** :
 `sem_access.sem_op = -1;` //this process will wait until condition not true

**process 2**: since in 1st process `sem_op` value is -1, this process needs to make `sem_op` value as 0 or 1 then only other process will get executed, So do like this

```
sem_access.sem_op = 1;
```

as man page of semop() says, If `sem_op` is a positive integer, the operation adds `this` value  to  the
       semaphore  value  `(semval)`. now sem_op becomes -1 + 1 = 0, refer again `semop()` man pages "This is a "`wait-for-zero`" operation: if semval is zero, the
       operation  can immediately proceed".

I hope you got some idea to resolve problem.

Comment: The process runs well but the variable index isn't incremented well. If I insert a sleep() before or after the increment it works well.

Comment: @JimBelushi  sleep is not correct solution for scheduling, Once done did you make semval value as 0 using semctl() or manually

Comment: I know it's not correct! The process execute the code after the semaphore one by one, so the semaphore works correctly however the variable index isn't correctly updated